# Widgets parsing using Hugo for hugo-academic

Tags: r, web, frameworks, r-markdown, hugo

I am using [academic framework](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/)  and I created a Hugo site that is working well for directory pages but not with widget pages defined using #page in the menus.toml file. The current version of Hugo is

> Hugo Static Site Generator v0.58.1-24277B92 windows/amd64 BuildDate:
>   2019-09-06T09:19:22Z

I got this error message when compiling the academic framework:

> ERROR building site: failed to render pages: render of "home" failed: 
>   /themems/academic/layouts/index.json:47:42 :
>   error calling append: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on Zero
>   value

yet, I checked the markup file related to this parameter and there is a value assigned already!

How to fix the widget parsing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Abrial. Can you add some details? You have told us that "parsing is not working", but without more information no-one here will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron for your comment. I have updated the post with further detailes.